# Java Spring - Browser isnt saving http only cookie

Tags: java, spring, cookies, spring-boot, jwt

I'm developing an app using spring-boot at my backend. I'm using an HTTP-Only Cookie, which I'm able to set it in Response-Header but not in browser. In response header - I get

```
Set-Cookie:"TOKEN=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIyNTQiLCJyb2xlcyI6MjU0LCJpYXQiOjE0Mzk4NzQ1OTh9.3FadMRuTESc3cF4-4BRt_lQ43atwUSJmwMkY3HUWAOE;HttpOnly",
```

Heres my **UserController.java**

```
String userIdString = String.valueOf(user.getId());
    String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(userIdString)
          .claim("roles", user.getId()).setIssuedAt(new Date())
          .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact();
 response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "TOKEN=" +  token + ";HttpOnly");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're working with an HTTPServletResponse object, in which case you want #addCookie()

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie)

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply but I have already tried using addCookie() too, but result is still the same. Cookie is not getting showed on browser but it is visible in ResponseHeader.

Comment: Does the cookie path and domain match your deployed web app? If they don't match then the browser will not associate them with the web page.

Comment: I am not very sure about the path but the domain is matching with deployed web app. We have not set any specific path yet.